# imresize (Two-element Cell Array Specifying Interpolation Kernel)

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I spent a month between trying and searching in this issue. All I want is that using bilinear interpolation with controlling the width of the mask.
I tried this

`M = @(x) 1./x;`

`I = imresize(im,10,{M,10});`

`im` is a gray scale image

Is this block of code will run correctly? If not, What is the correction of that? even what is the concept of specifying interpolation kernel?

thank you very much.

Note : I read the topics in stackoverflow which correlated with this topic. It wasn't that clear. I got nothing.

Comment: Try imfilter instead. imresize is not what you are after

Comment: I suggest you try: `I = imresize(im, 10, {M, 10}, 'bilinear');`. But why are you asking if the code is correct? The easiest way is to try and see for yourself.

Comment: you are right .. It doesn't run correctly .. but I meant "is this correct form of coding" .. that what I meant .. thank you man .. :)